# Combo box in subscene is not working in javaFX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

In the below example i'm trying to add a combo box inside a subscene. But it is not working correctly .If I select a value from the combo box ,it's is not set in the combobox and the combobox values are not displaying properly.

```
package javaFxExamples;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.When;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MeshCubeSubScene extends Application {

    double anchorX, anchorY;
    private static final float EDGE_LENGTH = 380;
    private double anchorAngleX = 0;
    private double anchorAngleY = 0;

    private final DoubleProperty angleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(25);
    private final DoubleProperty angleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(40);

    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);

    private Slider zSlider;
    private final DoubleProperty zPos = new SimpleDoubleProperty(-200);
    ComboBox comboBox;

    private CheckBox meshCheckBox;

    private final BooleanProperty showWireframe = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    static TriangleMesh createMesh(float w, float h, float d) {

        if (w * h * d == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        float hw = w / 2f;
        float hh = h / 2f;
        float hd = d / 2f;

        float x0 = 0f;
        float x1 = 1f / 4f;
        float x2 = 2f / 4f;
        float x3 = 3f / 4f;
        float x4 = 1f;
        float y0 = 0f;
        float y1 = 1f / 3f;
        float y2 = 2f / 3f;
        float y3 = 1f;

        TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
        mesh.getPoints().addAll(hw, hh, hd, // point A
                hw, hh, -hd, // point B
                hw, -hh, hd, // point C
                hw, -hh, -hd, // point D
                -hw, hh, hd, // point E
                -hw, hh, -hd, // point F
                -hw, -hh, hd, // point G
                -hw, -hh, -hd // point H
        );
        mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(x1, y0, x2, y0, x0, y1, x1, y1, x2, y1, x3, y1, x4, y1, x0, y2, x1, y2, x2,
                y2, x3, y2, x4, y2, x1, y3, x2, y3);
        mesh.getFaces().addAll(0, 10, 2, 5, 1, 9, // triangle A-C-B
                2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 9, // triangle C-D-B
                4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 2, // triangle E-F-G
                6, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, // triangle G-F-H
                0, 13, 1, 9, 4, 12, // triangle A-B-E
                4, 12, 1, 9, 5, 8, // triangle E-B-F
                2, 1, 6, 0, 3, 4, // triangle C-G-D
                3, 4, 6, 0, 7, 3, // triangle D-G-H
                0, 10, 4, 11, 2, 5, // triangle A-E-C
                2, 5, 4, 11, 6, 6, // triangle C-E-G
                1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8, // triangle B-D-F
                5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 3 // triangle F-D-H
        );
        mesh.getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5);
        return mesh;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("MeshCubeSubScene");

        Image diffuseMap = new Image(MeshCubeSubScene.class.getResource("cbGn_pof-bm.png").toExternalForm());

        PhongMaterial earthMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        earthMaterial.setDiffuseMap(diffuseMap);

        MeshView cube = new MeshView(createMesh(EDGE_LENGTH, EDGE_LENGTH, EDGE_LENGTH));
        cube.setMaterial(earthMaterial);

        final Group parent = new Group(cube);
        parent.setTranslateX(450);
        parent.setTranslateY(400);
        parent.setTranslateZ(0);

        Rotate xRotate;
        Rotate yRotate;
        parent.getTransforms().setAll(xRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS),
                yRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
        xRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleX);
        yRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleY);

        final Group root = new Group(parent);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 900, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();
            anchorAngleX = angleX.get();
            anchorAngleY = angleY.get();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            angleX.set(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()));
            angleY.set(anchorAngleY + anchorX - event.getSceneX());
        });

        PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
        pointLight.setTranslateX(300);
        pointLight.setTranslateY(200);
        pointLight.setTranslateZ(-2000);

        root.getChildren().add(pointLight);

        scene.setCamera(camera);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // SubScene code
        PerspectiveCamera subSceneCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        scene.setCamera(subSceneCamera);
        Label zLabel = new Label("Z");
        zSlider = new Slider(-200, 3000, -200);
        meshCheckBox = new CheckBox("Wireframe");
        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().add("test1");
        comboBox.getItems().add("test2");
        comboBox.getItems().add("test3");

        HBox subSceneGroup = new HBox(70, new HBox(10, zLabel, zSlider), meshCheckBox, comboBox);
        subSceneGroup.setPadding(new Insets(100, 100, 0, 100));
        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(subSceneGroup, 600, 200);
        subScene.setLayoutX(180);
        subScene.setLayoutY(720);

        root.getChildren().add(subScene);

        // Setup binding
        zSlider.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(zPos);
        parent.translateZProperty().bind(zPos);

        meshCheckBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(showWireframe);
        cube.drawModeProperty().bind(new When(showWireframe).then(DrawMode.LINE).otherwise(DrawMode.FILL));

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm .. can't reproduce (adjusting the sizes a bit to really see the combo), fx17: it starts empty and after selecting a value in the dropdown, that value is shown as selected. Might have been a bug that's fixed some time in the last decade?